# Another django NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, url, reverse

In project.urls:

```
url(r'^category/', include('category.urls')),
```

In project/category/category.urls (patterns prefixed with 'project.category.views'):

```
url(r'^list/', 'category_list', name='category_list_name'),
```

In project/templates/base.html:

```
{% url 'category_list_name' %}
```

Gives me:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for ''category_list_name'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

In the shell, I get the same error for this:

```
>>> reverse(category.views.category_list)
```

But this works fine:

```
>>> reverse("category_list_name")
u'/en/category/list/'
```

In a view, I get an empty string for reversing the named url.
Like you see I'm also using localeurl, but I think that shouldn't matter?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{% url 'category_list_name' %}` looks like you are using Django 1.3 but do you have `{% load url from future %}` in your template? If not you should use `{% url category_list_name %}` instead. Quotes make all the difference.